# Add new validate method to jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, linkedin-api

I want to validate LinkedIn profile URL. This is not a required field but when the user enters the data it should only allow the regex format. When it did not match it should show the message as invalid. I have tried like this but it not even triggering. How can I debug it?

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("linkedinUrl", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /(ftp|http|https):\/\/?(?:www\.)?linkedin.com(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:([0-9])+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(value);
});

$(function() {
  $("#Add_Staff_Form").validate({
    rules: {
      linkedin {
        required: true;
        linkedinUrl: true;
      }
    },
    messages: {
      linkedin {
        required: "Please specify the correct linkedin url"
      }
    },
    ignore: ':hidden:not([class~=selectized]),:hidden > .selectized, .selectize-control .selectize-input input'
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label class="control-label">Linkedin</label>
  <input type="text" id="linkedin" name="linkedin" class="form-control" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:

```
<script>
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("linkedinUrl", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /(ftp|http|https):\/\/?(?:www\.)?linkedin.com(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:([0-9])+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(value); }, "Please enter valid linkedin url!" );

    $(function () {
        $("#Add_Staff_Form").validate({
            rules: {
                linkedin:"linkedinUrl",
            },
            ignore: ':hidden:not([class~=selectized]),:hidden > .selectized, .selectize-control .selectize-input input'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Add this in html:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label  class="control-label">Linkedin</label>
    <input type="text" id="linkedin" name="linkedin" class="form-control linkedinUrl" value=""   />
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain how/why your code is different from what the OP already posted.